# Make grouped rows whose difference in date is within 30 days TRUE for ALL the true instances

Tags: r

I am trying to look within a group, calculate the days difference between each row for 1 individual ID, and flag if the days difference falls within a 30 day period.

Mock data-

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
  Date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01", "2011-01-01", "2011-01-29", "2012-04-27", "2012-10-01", "2013-08-15", "2013-12-12", "2014-01-01", "2014-03-02", "2014-09-17", "2014-09-17"))
)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
  LagDate = lag(Date), 
  Diff = Date - LagDate,
  InWindow = ifelse(Diff < 30, T, F)
)

      ID Date       LagDate    Diff     InWindow
   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <drtn>   <lgl>   
 1     1 2011-01-01 NA          NA days NA      
 2     1 2011-01-01 2011-01-01   0 days TRUE    
 3     1 2011-01-29 2011-01-01  28 days TRUE    
 4     1 2012-04-27 2011-01-29 454 days FALSE   
 5     2 2012-10-01 NA          NA days NA      
 6     2 2013-08-15 2012-10-01 318 days FALSE   
 7     3 2013-12-12 NA          NA days TRUE
 8     3 2014-01-01 2013-12-12  20 days TRUE    
 9     3 2014-03-02 2014-01-01  60 days FALSE   
10     4 2014-09-17 NA          NA days NA      
11     4 2014-09-17 2014-09-17   0 days TRUE
```

I know that from the lag(Date) piece of code, you cannot lag the first incident, hence the NA's. But, what I need to be able to do is pull out all rows where the difference between the 2 dates is under the 30 day period. So, I would need to assign the value of the second row used in the calculation to the first (since the second row calculates and designates a T/F according to the first date). I honestly would only need the flag variable to take a T/F value- mock output would ideally look like this-

```
      ID Date       LagDate    Diff     InWindow
   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <drtn>   <lgl>   
 1     1 2011-01-01 NA          NA days TRUE      
 2     1 2011-01-01 2011-01-01   0 days TRUE    
 3     1 2011-01-29 2011-01-01  28 days TRUE    
 4     1 2012-04-27 2011-01-29 454 days FALSE   
 5     2 2012-10-01 NA          NA days FALSE      
 6     2 2013-08-15 2012-10-01 318 days FALSE   
 7     3 2013-12-12 NA          NA days FALSE      
 8     3 2014-01-01 2013-12-12  20 days TRUE    
 9     3 2014-03-02 2014-01-01  60 days FALSE   
10     4 2014-09-17 NA          NA days TRUE      
11     4 2014-09-17 2014-09-17   0 days TRUE
```

Is there any way I can take the non-lagged (second row in each individual group) flag variable's designation and assign it to the first row used for the lag within each group?

Comment: Should row 7 be TRUE since the next date is < 30 days away?

Comment: Whoops... Oversight on my end, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more concise way, but this counts as TRUE any row within 30 days of the prior or following observation in the same group.

```
df |>
  mutate(InWindow = coalesce(lead(Date) - Date < 30, 0) | 
           coalesce(Date - lag(Date) < 30, 0), .by = ID)


   ID       Date InWindow
1   1 2011-01-01     TRUE
2   1 2011-01-01     TRUE
3   1 2011-01-29     TRUE
4   1 2012-04-27    FALSE
5   2 2012-10-01    FALSE
6   2 2013-08-15    FALSE
7   3 2013-12-12     TRUE # FALSE in example, intentional?
8   3 2014-01-01     TRUE
9   3 2014-03-02    FALSE
10  4 2014-09-17     TRUE
11  4 2014-09-17     TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I originally subset my data on a grouped dataframe so I was hitting a few obstacles on my real dataset, but I threw this code before I started working with my grouped dataframe and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much for the help, apologies about the oversight on row 7.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `ifelse` or the like since `Diff < 30` already yields boolean. Take care of `NA` dates, which shouldn't be `TRUE` I guess, using `(is.na(Diff) & !is.na(Date))`. Here a base R solution.

```
within(df, {
  LagDate <- ave(Date, ID, FUN=\(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)])) |> as.Date()
  Diff <- Date - LagDate
  InWindow <- Diff < 30 | (is.na(Diff) & !is.na(Date))
})
#    ID       Date InWindow     Diff    LagDate
# 1   1 2011-01-01     TRUE  NA days       <NA>
# 2   1 2011-01-01     TRUE   0 days 2011-01-01
# 3   1 2011-01-29     TRUE  28 days 2011-01-01
# 4   1 2012-04-27    FALSE 454 days 2011-01-29
# 5   2 2012-10-01     TRUE  NA days       <NA>
# 6   2 2013-08-15    FALSE 318 days 2012-10-01
# 7   3 2013-12-12     TRUE  NA days       <NA>
# 8   3 2014-01-01     TRUE  20 days 2013-12-12
# 9   3 2014-03-02    FALSE  60 days 2014-01-01
# 10  4 2014-09-17     TRUE  NA days       <NA>
# 11  4 2014-09-17     TRUE   0 days 2014-09-17
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), Date = structure(c(14975, 
14975, 15003, 15457, 15614, 15932, 16051, 16071, 16131, 16330, 
16330), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```